# Does "midbrain activation" cause clairvoyance?

Tags: neurology, esp

There was this kid in my town who claimed that his instructor had trained him using Mid-Brain Activation, see [Midbrain Activation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midbrain_Activation)) techniques, and as a result he could "see" things while being blindfolded. He performed this in front of me wherein he would identify some business cards (some of them presented by us) and could read and do many things while being blindfolded. I thought this was some sort of trick and shrugged it off.

Months later a similar boy's video (they could be the same. I don't remember exactly) has appeared on a show about India on History TV 18.

Video link: https://youtu.be/uC8rU0H70nw

Is this video genuine? Can midbrain activation cause clairvoyance?

Comment: Ah, the [Used To Be About History Channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5an9wxIbUMM).

Comment: This has been disproven by physics, given the properties of photons. If they are blocked by a sufficiently thick blindfold, the visual information does not reach the eyes. Not sure any additional "proof" is needed.

Comment: How does it work? Well, clearly he can see through the blindfold...

Comment: @Sklivvz - entangled photon pairs? :)

Comment: @Peter Of course I know that.

Comment: @Sklivvz Don't you think they would have ensured that he can't see through it before showing the stuff on national television?

Comment: Why would you assume that? There are tons of stage magicians on national tv.

Comment: @Sklivvz Okay. So, let's assume that this is a fun exercise where we have to debunk that magician. So, ""He could see through it" sounds too obvious.

Comment: It looks like he is able to see out of the bottom of the blindfold. When he is catching the things thrown at him, you can see him holding his head up in a way that would let him see the things being thrown. That could also explain why he can ride the moped just fine, because he goes slow enough that he can maneuver by peeking out of the bottom of the blindfold to see anything that might be coming up.